# Removing next node function not working, what is going wrong with my free() statement?

Tags: c, function, linked-list

When I call this function it usually works fine, however the program breaks when I call the free function on the variable "temp_ptr"

the function below doesn't work:

```
void remove_next_node(Node** current_list_ptr)
{
    Node* temp_ptr = (*current_list_ptr)->link;

    (*current_list_ptr)->link = (*current_list_ptr)->link->link;

    free(temp_ptr); //<- it breaks when the function gets to this line

}
```

here is the entire program

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PATIENT_STRING_SIZE 10
#define REFERENCE_STRING_SIZE 100
#define DELIMETER_CHAR ','
#define DELIMETER_STRING ","
#define INVALID_CHAR 'A'

typedef enum sleep
{
    NONE = 0,
    ASLEEP = 1,
    AWAKE = 2,
    REALLY_AWAKE = 3,
    INVALID_FEILD = 4
} Sleep;

typedef struct fit_bit_data
{
    char patient[10];
    char minute[9];
    double calories;
    double distance;
    unsigned int floors;
    unsigned int heart_rate;
    unsigned int steps;
    Sleep sleep_level;
} Fit_bit_data;

typedef struct node
{
    Fit_bit_data data;
    struct node* link;
} Node;

void populate_list(Node**, FILE*);

void line_clean(char*);

void string_insert(char*, int, int);

void insert_node_front(Node**, Fit_bit_data*);

Node* make_node(Fit_bit_data*);

void remove_duplicates_from_list(Node*);

void remove_next_node(Node**);

void print_list_to_output_file(Node*, FILE*);

int main(void)
{
    FILE* data_stream = NULL, * output_stream = NULL;
    //data_stream = fopen("fit_bit_data.csv", "r");
    data_stream = fopen("sample_data.csv", "r");
    output_stream = fopen("output_file_PA01.csv", "w");

    Node* list_head = NULL;

    if (data_stream == NULL) /* checking if the file was opened */
    {
        printf("something went wrong while opening the file\n\n");
        return 0;
    }


    populate_list(&list_head, data_stream);

    remove_duplicates_from_list(list_head);

    print_list_to_output_file(list_head, output_stream);

    fclose(data_stream);
    fclose(output_stream);

    return 0;
}

void populate_list(Node** list_head, FILE* data_stream)
{
    char reference_string[REFERENCE_STRING_SIZE] = { '\0' }, target[10] = { '\0' };

    Fit_bit_data reference_data = { "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    int i = 0, comparison = 1;

    /***************************************************************************************************************************************/

    fgets(reference_string, REFERENCE_STRING_SIZE, data_stream);

    strtok(reference_string, DELIMETER_STRING);

    strcpy(target, strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING)); /* this gets the target */

    fgets(reference_string, REFERENCE_STRING_SIZE, data_stream); /* reading in the garbage line of data */

    for (i; fgets(reference_string, REFERENCE_STRING_SIZE, data_stream) != NULL; ++i) /* going to keep track of how many lines I read, just for future debugging*/
    {
        line_clean(reference_string); /* clean the line up */

        comparison = strcmp(target, strtok(reference_string, DELIMETER_STRING));

        if (comparison == 0) /* seeing if we have the target value at hand */
        {
            reference_string[5] = ','; /* this line took me several days to finally figure out that I needed it */
            strcpy(reference_data.patient, strtok(reference_string, DELIMETER_STRING));
            strcpy(reference_data.minute, strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING));
            reference_data.calories = strtod((strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING)), NULL);
            reference_data.distance = strtod((strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING)), NULL);
            reference_data.floors = atoi(strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING));
            reference_data.heart_rate = atoi(strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING));
            reference_data.steps = atoi(strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING));
            reference_data.sleep_level = atoi(strtok(NULL, DELIMETER_STRING));

            insert_node_front(list_head, &reference_data);
        }
    }

}

void insert_node_front(Node** list_head, Fit_bit_data* data)
{
    Node* new_node = NULL;

    new_node = make_node(data); /* allocates space for the node on the heap and populates it */

    if (new_node != NULL)
    {
        new_node->link = *list_head; /* make the link for the new node the link that connects the rest of the list */
        *list_head = new_node;       /* update the head pointer for the list to point to the new node */
    }

}

Node* make_node(Fit_bit_data* data)
{
    Node* new_node = NULL;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Fit_bit_data));

    if (new_node != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(new_node->data.patient, data->patient); /* this sucks to type out */
        strcpy(new_node->data.minute, data->minute);
        new_node->data.calories = data->calories;
        new_node->data.distance = data->distance;
        new_node->data.floors = data->floors;
        new_node->data.heart_rate = data->heart_rate;
        new_node->data.steps = data->steps;
        new_node->data.sleep_level = data->sleep_level;

        new_node->link = NULL;
    }

    return new_node;

}

void line_clean(char* string)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, delimeter_occurence = 0, string_length = 0;

    char temp = '\0';

    string_length = strlen(string);

    if (string[0] == DELIMETER_CHAR) /* if the patient feild is empty, then we will make it so the data line is just invalid */
    {
        strcpy(string, "INVALID,");
        return;
    }

    for (i; (i < REFERENCE_STRING_SIZE) && (string[i] != '\0'); ++i)
    {
        if ((string[i] == DELIMETER_CHAR) && (string[i - 1] != '\0')) /* this allows me to know where I am in the string */
        {
            ++delimeter_occurence;
        }

        if ((string[i] == DELIMETER_CHAR) && (string[i + 1] == DELIMETER_CHAR)) /* in this case we know that there are back to back delimeters ",," */
        {

            switch (delimeter_occurence)
            {
            case 1: /* feild 2 (minute) */
                string_insert(string, i, delimeter_occurence);
                break;
            case 2: /* feild 3 (calories) */
                string_insert(string, i, delimeter_occurence);
                break;
            case 3: /* feild 4 (distance) */
                string_insert(string, i, delimeter_occurence);
                break;
            case 4: /* feild 5 (floors) */
                string_insert(string, i, delimeter_occurence);
                break;
            case 5: /* feild 6 (heart rate) */
                string_insert(string, i, delimeter_occurence);
                break;
            case 6: /* feild 7 (steps) */
                string_insert(string, i, delimeter_occurence);
                break;
            }
        }

        if ((string[i] == DELIMETER_CHAR) && (string[i + 1] == '\0')) /* feild 8 (sleep level) */
        {
            string_insert(string, i, delimeter_occurence);
        }
    }
}

void string_insert(char* string, int position, int delimeter_count)
{
    int size_string = 0, number = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    size_string = strlen(string);

    switch (delimeter_count)
    {
    case 1: /* feild 2 (minute) */
        number = 1;
        break;
    case 2: /* feild 3 (calories) */
        number = 2;
        break;
    case 3: /* feild 4 (distance) */
        number = 2;
        break;
    case 4: /* feild 5 (floors) */
        number = 10;
        break;
    case 5: /* feild 6 (heart rate) */
        number = 10;
        break;
    case 6: /* feild 7 (steps) */
        number = 10;
        break;
    case 7: /* feild 8 (sleep level) */
        number = 1;
        break;
    }

    for (j = position + 1, k = 0; j < size_string + 1; ++j, ++k)
    {
        string[size_string - k + number] = string[size_string - k];
    }

    for (j = position + 1; j < number + 1 + position; ++j)
    {
        string[j] = '_';
    }

    switch (delimeter_count)
    {
    case 1: /* feild 2 (minute) */
        string[position + 1] = INVALID_CHAR;
        break;
    case 2: /* feild 3 (calories) */
        string[position + 1] = '-';
        string[position + 2] = '1';
        break;
    case 3: /* feild 4 (distance) */
        string[position + 1] = '-';
        string[position + 2] = '1';
        break;
    case 4: /* feild 5 (floors) */
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            string[position + j + 1] = '1';
        }
        break;
    case 5: /* feild 6 (heart rate) */
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            string[position + j + 1] = '1';
        }
        break;
    case 6: /* feild 7 (steps) */
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            string[position + j + 1] = '1';
        }
        break;
    case 7: /* feild 8 (sleep level) */
        string[position + 1] = '4';
        break;
    }

}

void remove_duplicates_from_list(Node* list_head)
{
    Node* current_ptr = list_head;
    int cmp_result = 0;

    while (current_ptr->link != NULL)
    {
        cmp_result = strcmp(current_ptr->data.minute, current_ptr->link->data.minute);

        if (cmp_result == 0)
        {
            remove_next_node(&current_ptr);
        }
        else
        {
            current_ptr = current_ptr->link;
        }
    }
}

void remove_next_node(Node** current_list_ptr)
{
    Node* temp_ptr = (*current_list_ptr)->link;

    (*current_list_ptr)->link = (*current_list_ptr)->link->link;

    free(temp_ptr);

}

void print_list_to_output_file(Node* list_ptr, FILE* output_stream)
{
    if (list_ptr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        print_list_to_output_file(list_ptr->link, output_stream);
    }

    fprintf(output_stream, "%s,%s,%lf,%lf,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",
        list_ptr->data.patient, list_ptr->data.minute,
        list_ptr->data.calories, list_ptr->data.distance,
        list_ptr->data.floors, list_ptr->data.heart_rate,
        list_ptr->data.steps, list_ptr->data.sleep_level);
}
```

here is what the data in the .csv file looks like:

Target: ,12cx7,,,,,,
Patient,minute,calories,distance,floors,heart,steps,sleep_level
12cx7,0:00:00,0.968900025,0,0,63,0,1
12cx7,0:01:00,0.968900025,0,0,67,0,1
12cx7,0:02:00,0.968900025,0,0,69,0,1
12cx7,0:03:00,0.968900025,0,0,70,0,1
12cx7,0:04:00,0.968900025,0,0,70,0,1
12cx7,0:05:00,0.968900025,0,0,71,0,1
12cx7,0:05:00,0.968900025,0,0,71,0,1
12cx7,0:06:00,0.968900025,0,0,69,0,1
12cx7,0:07:00,0.968900025,0,0,71,0,1
12cx7,0:08:00,0.968900025,0,0,68,0,1
12cx7,0:09:00,0.968900025,0,0,67,0,1
12cx7,0:10:00,0.968900025,0,0,66,0,1
12ax7,0:10:00,0.968900025,0,0,66,0,1
12cx7,0:11:00,0.968900025,0,0,65,0,1
12cx7,0:12:00,0.968900025,0,0,65,0,1
12cx7,0:13:00,0.968900025,0,0,67,0,1
12cx7,0:14:00,0.968900025,0,0,65,0,1
12cx7,0:15:00,0.968900025,0,0,63,0,1
12cx7,0:16:00,0.968900025,0,0,64,0,1
12cx7,0:17:00,0.968900025,0,0,63,0,1
12cx7,0:18:00,0.968900025,0,0,63,0,1
12cx7,0:19:00,0.968900025,0,0,65,0,1
12cx7,0:20:00,0.968900025,0,0,64,0,1
12cx7,0:21:00,0.968900025,0,0,63,0,1
12cx7,0:21:00,0.968900025,0,0,63,0,1

(there are about 1400 lines like this and there are some missing fields which are dealt with the line clean function)

Comment: almost certainly you have trashed your heap. Please post a complete program. Othersiwse run under valgrind

Comment: What is a Node? What is a Node->link? As @pm100 said, you need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can compile it and test it. Edit your question to contain code we can run.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: there is no main here

Comment: ok I added the entire program

Comment: It works fine as long as there current_list_ptr isn't NULL: https://onlinegdb.com/He3QOjUR0

Comment: `cool_starting_sequence()` is still not defined. If it wasn't 1am I'd maybe try to debug your 300+ line minimal example, but I can't.

Comment: I use visual studio community and I am getting the debug error "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"

Comment: whoops, meant 1400 lines

Comment: You could get rid of a ton of code simply by using `strchr()` to find the next delimiter (a single comma), and NOT trying to transform the string so that `strtok()` can be used to find fabricated fields...

Comment: strcpy into fixed size strings without checking their size (target, patient, minute etc).

Comment: godbolt showed me 21 warnings. First fix them.

Answer (score 0):

1. `make_node()`: The main problem is that you allocate a `Fit_bit_data` but assign it to a `Node *`:

```
Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(Fit_bit_data));
```

A good way to avoid this error is to use the variable instead of the type.  With this change valgrind is happy (other than leaks):

```
Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
```

2. main(): Here is how to fix the leaks:

```
void remove_nodes(Node **n) {
    if(!n) return;
    while(*n) {
        Node *tmp = *n;
        *n = (*n)->link;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

// ...
    print_list_to_output_file(list_head, output_stream);
    remove_nodes(&list_head);
    fclose(data_stream);
// ...
```

Maybe create a `remove_node()` then use it here and in `remove_next_node()`?

3. `remove_duplicates_from_list()`: dereference list_head without a null check.
4. `make_node()`: re comment, you can change:

```
    if (new_node != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(new_node->data.patient, data->patient); /* this sucks to type out */
        strcpy(new_node->data.minute, data->minute);
        new_node->data.calories = data->calories;
        new_node->data.distance = data->distance;
        new_node->data.floors = data->floors;
        new_node->data.heart_rate = data->heart_rate;
        new_node->data.steps = data->steps;
        new_node->data.sleep_level = data->sleep_level;

        new_node->link = NULL;
    }
```

to:

```
    if (new_node) {
        memcpy(&new_node->data, data, sizeof(*data));
        new_node->link = NULL;
    }
```

5. If you don't implement error checks then you are wasting your and our time (`malloc()`, `fopen()` etc).